# Make variables not "reset" in sub-make

Tags: makefile

I'm seeing some interesting behaviour with variables passed to a Sub-make. I've made a toy example project with the following layout:

```
./make_test
| -- foo
|   \ -- Makefile
\ -- Makefile
```

`make_test/Makefile`

```
.PHONY: deps
deps:
        $(MAKE) -C foo

.PHONY: deps2
deps2: export SOME_VAR=something
deps2:
        $(MAKE) -C foo
```

`make_test/foo/Makefile`

```
SOME_VAR ?= something
$(info 1 - SOME_VAR=$(SOME_VAR))

SOME_VAR += else
$(info 2 - SOME_VAR=$(SOME_VAR))

all: deps
        @$(MAKE) app

.PHONY: deps
deps:
        $(info Getting deps)

app: foo_a foo_b
        touch app

foo_a:
        touch foo_a

foo_b:
        touch foo_b
```

The results of running `make deps`

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C foo
1 - SOME_VAR=something
2 - SOME_VAR=something else
Getting deps
1 - SOME_VAR=something
2 - SOME_VAR=something else
make[2]: `app' is up to date.
```

The results of running `make deps2`

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C foo
1 - SOME_VAR=something
2 - SOME_VAR=something else
Getting deps
1 - SOME_VAR=something else
2 - SOME_VAR=something else else
make[2]: `app' is up to date.
```

I understand that `SOME_VAR` is evaluated twice. However, for `deps` the end result is `something else` whereas `deps2` results in `something else else`.

My question is, why does the value of `SOME_VAR` "reset" before the second evaluation when calling `deps` but not `deps2`. Why having the initial  value passed through to the sub-make affect this?

Answer (score 0):

If you `export` a variable, that variable will be recursively `export`ed unless you `unexport` it later on.

When you invoke `$(MAKE)` in `foo/Makefile` it `export`s `SOME_VAR` as `something else` because you told make to `export` it in the root makefile.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent this behaviour but still pass a value through to a sub-make? I know I could use `findstring` to check if `else` has already been appended to `SOME_VAR` but is there a better way?

Comment: @GuessBurger I think your example is too contrived to answer that, without a real-world example of what you're trying to do all I can say is you probably shouldn't be recursing into the same folder.